# Is it possible to use vim-fugitive outside of the repository (in local mounted directory)

Tags: git, plugin-fugitive

I have a git repository: `~/home/foo/repo`

I mounted core to another directory:

`mount --bind ~/home/foo/repo ~/home/bar`

Now I want to edit my code with vim and use vim-fugitive.
`vim ~/home/bar/myCode.txt; :Gblame`

Answer (score 3):

According to [vim-fugitive sources](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive/blob/master/autoload/fugitive.vim), you can use Fugitive commands for any file that belongs to git index.
E.g.

```sh
cd ~
vim ~/home/foo/repo/README.md # works
vim ~/home/bar/README.md # works too
```

Comment: Well, It is not working for me. I do not think that the file belongs to the `git index` because it is outside of my repository and I am accessing this file as a link.

Comment: well ... do you have `.git.` directory ?


`ls ~/home/bar/.git`

Comment: This is exactly my problem. I want to access it outside of the `.git` directory tree. `~/home/foo/repo/.git` exists and `~/home/bar/.git` does not

Comment: @Kfir Is the `mount` command in the question the exact one you ran? I just tried it, and for me, after running the mount command, `~/home/bar/.git` *does* exist, and therefore fugitive should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution. Put `set autochdir` in your .vimrc. vim-fugitive can't know where the repo of the current file is if it is outside of the .git folder.